# Deleting the word and the word/character next to it in a string inside file

Tags: bash, shell

I am looking to solve a particular problem in Bash scripting

Consider file.txt

```
AAAA BBBB  CCCC D  EEEE F
```

I am looking to delete CCCC and D and restore the space it occupies so that there is not extra space as such

I have tried using sed but to no avail. Tried using the s option but it is working only for the string where I can replace it with ''

The expected result is

```
AAAA BBBB  EEEE F
```

Comment: Please do add your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem in your post and let us know then.

Comment: So you want to just replace the string `'CCCC D  '` or replace the string at the position of 3 and 4?

Comment: Are all of the spaces in your file blank chars or are some tabs? Does your file use fixed width or varying width fields? Posting more than just 1 line of input and output would be a huge help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm correctly interpreting that "extra space" means more than one space, then I'm confused as to why the expected result has two spaces between "BBBB" and "EEEE".   Assuming you really meant one space, the following should work:

```
$ echo "AAAA BBBB  CCCC D  EEEE F  " | sed 's/CCCC D//g' | tr -s ' '
AAAA BBBB EEEE F
```

Comment: Yes it means there is more that one space. there is extra space. It is becase of the requirement but I do not need it